# rails group matching dates in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an array that stems from associations. I'm looking to produce a table displaying the data in a table series, matching each row of data to the date.

There can be many treatments ranging from 1 - 6, but there will always be 3 entries for each treatment.

**Controller**

```
@trial = Trial.find(params[:trial_id])
@max_length = [@trial.treatment_selections].map(&:size).max
```

**Model**

```
has_many :treatment_selections, primary_key: 'trial_id'
has_many :assessments, primary_key: 'trial_id'
has_many :methods, through: :assessments
```

**Table structure**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Degree</th>
 <% @max_length.times do |data| %>
 <th><%= @trial.treatment_selections[data].try(:treatment).try(:name) %></th>
 <% end %>
 <% @trial.methods.order(:treatment_selection_id).order("assessment_date ASC").group(:assessment_id).each do |e| %>
      <tr>
      <td><%= Time.at(e.try(:assessment).try(:assessment_date)/1000).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") rescue 0 %></td>
      <td><%= e.try(:assessment).try(:degrees) rescue 0 %></td>
      <% @trial.methods.order(:treatment_selection_id).order("assessment_date ASC").group(:treatment_selection_id).each do |f| %>
      <td><%= f.try(:total).round(1) rescue 0 %></td>
      <% end %>
      </tr> 
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </table>
```

The above code displays the following:

[image]

It seems to repeat the first assessment data for each treatment in each row. When in fact there should be more data show, like this:

[image]

**Schemas**

```
 create_table "methods", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "treatment_selection_id"
    t.integer "assessment_id"
    t.float "total"
  end

  create_table "treatment_selections", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "trial_id", limit: 36
    t.integer "treatment_id", limit: 36
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.text "bar_code"
  end

  create_table "assessments", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "trial_id", limit: 36
    t.bigint "assessment_date"
    t.integer "degrees"
    t.integer "flowering"
    t.integer "sowing"
    t.integer "hot_days"
  end
```

Output of **@trial.treatment_selections.inspect**

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Treatment_selection id: 372, trial_id: 121, treatment_id: 2, quantity: nil, ginBarCode: nil>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Treatment_selection id: 373, trial_id: 121, treatment_id: 1, quantity: nil, ginBarCode: nil>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Treatment_selection id: 374, trial_id: 121, treatment_id: 3, quantity: nil, ginBarCode: nil>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Treatment_selection id: 375, trial_id: 121, treatment_id: 4, quantity: nil, ginBarCode: nil>]>
```

Output of **@trial.inspect**

```
#<Trial id: 121, repetitions: 3, area: 18.0, comment: nil, no_of_treatment: 4, created_at: 1531358319000, update_at: 1531358319000>
```

Output of **@trial.methods.inspect**

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Method id: 1114, treatment_selection_id: 372, assessment_id: 98, total: 0.1>, #<Method id: 1115, treatment_selection_id: 372, assessment_id: 98, total: 2.1> ... etc
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `@trial.treatment_selections.inspect` and `@trial.inspect`?

Comment: Can you share the schema for all the models mentioned in your question?

Comment: Added schemas to post.

Comment: added output of @trial.treatment_selections.inspect above as well.

Comment: Also `@trial.inspect` and `@trial.methods.inspect` if you can. Anyway, check if adding `distinct` solves your problem: `@trial.methods.distinct.order(:treatment_selection_id)......`

Comment: Thanks @iGian I have added the other two inspect outputs. Added distinct had no changes to the result.

Comment: I guess you need to get rid of the `<% @max_length.times do |data| %>` for the rows and instead of `.in_groups_of(3)` write the query to group by `assessment_id`. So you get the four columns for the treatments. But without full informations about relations between all tables and data (better the full `@trial.methods`) it's hard to provide some code snippet.

Comment: Thanks iGian. I think that was a majority of my issues the @max_length. I shall update the above with what I'm currently experience since updating the code.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but something sounds strange in your data or expected output. Does treatments of the same row share the same date record? Is it possible that Treatment 1 has a different date from Treatment 2? Can you post the full `@trial.methods.to_json`?